# Limit values a user can use in a Flask URL parameter

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask view that accepts a url parameter `old_del`, which can only accept 3 values: 'comma', 'pipe', and 'tab'.

```
@app.route('/jobs/change-file-del/<str:file_location>/<str:old_del>') 
def process_feed(file_location, old_del='tab'):
    ...
```

I want to return an error if the user includes an invalid value for `old_del`. I can accomplish this using an `assert` statement, but is there a way to do this specifically with Flask?

Comment: what returns the view, a specific template or an ajax response ? why not display a message `if old_del not in { 'comma', 'pipe', 'tab'}`: ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a built-in [`any`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/routing/#werkzeug.routing.AnyConverter) URL converter. Use that to specify the valid values. If it doesn't match, you'll get a 404.

```
@app.route('/jobs/change/<str:name>/<any(comma, pipe, tab):delim>')
def process_feed(name, delim='tab'):
    pass
```

If you want to do a more complex check, you can [write your own converter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30316314/400617) instead.